# Contagem baseada no valor de um campo e filtro de index no Elasticsearch com elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

Estou usando Python3.6, com `elasticsearch (7.9.1)` e `elasticsearch-dsl (7.3.0)`.

No meu index `logstash-2020.09.21` eu tenho alguns documentos conforme abaixo (filtrado pelos campos relevantes):

```
{
    "subtype": "webfilter",
    "url": "https://play.google.com/",
    ...
}
```

Eu posso fazer uma requisição `curl` e obter a informação que eu preciso desta forma:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/logstash-2020.09.21/_search?size=0&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "aggs": {
    "urls": {
      "filter": { "term": { "subtype": "webfilter" } },
      "aggs": {
        "count": { "terms": { "field": "url", "size": 100 } }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Que retorna alguns `buckets` como:

```
"buckets" : [
    {
        "key" : "https://play.google.com/",
        "doc_count" : 30783
    }
]
```

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer uma requisição equivalente usando `elasticsearch-dsl`, mas estou com  dificuldades para adaptar a composição da query.

Segue o que eu tentei até o momento:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q, A, Search

a = A("filter", Q("term", subtype="webfilter"))

client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search(using=client, index="logstash-2020.09.21")

s.aggs.bucket("urls", a).bucket("count", "terms", field="url", size=100)

s.execute()
```

Cuja saída é:

```
{
    "subtype": "local",
    "url": "/",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a consulta/filtros e depois realizar a agregação, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Q, A, Search

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_HOST, 'port': es_settings.ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}])
s = Search(using=es, index="logstash-2020.09.21", size=100)

# Size
s = s[0:40]

agg_urls = A('terms', field='urls')
s.aggs.bucket('qtd_url', agg_urls)
s.execute()
```